# How to check whether day light savings enabled for the given UTC offset?

Tags: c++, c, linux, redhat

I need to determine whether day light savings enabled for a given UTC offset in Linux(Redhat).
I get input such as UTC+05:30.
I checked the usage of zdump command. When used with time zone name, we can check the value of isdst in the output to determine the status of daylight-savings.

> zdump -v /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata | grep 2013

As above, zdump requires zone name. It doesn't accept UTC offset.

I also tried localtime function as below.

```
time_t currtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
timeinfo = localtime ( &currtime );
time_t local = mktime( timeinfo );
cout<<timeinfo->tm_isdst<<endl;
```

The above code works when time zone name is set in date time settings. It doesn't work if system is using UTC time. I used **gmtime** instead of localtime when UTC time is used.

Please let me know if there is any way to determine whether dst is enabled or not using UTC offset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is in general not possible. UTC+05:30 might be used by many countries, each with a different daylight savings time policy.

Answer (score 2):

UTC offset isn't enough to determine whether DST is enabled, as some jurisdictions don't use DST. Furthermore, those that do have different schedules for when it goes into effect (e.g., places in the southern hemisphere vs. places in the northern hemisphere). What you need is an up to date table that has the time zone names that use DST and when DST starts and stops for each.